# Is it possible to make a program that can read from a file, but you can't open the file from outside the program?

Tags: python, security

Basically, I have built a login system.

- The first time that a user uses the login system, a text file is created and the username and password are saved there when the user uses a "remember password?" function.
- The second time the software uses the system, the system already has the user and password typed in if the user previously used the "remember password?" function.

The thing is, the text file where the password and user are stored can be accessed by simply just going to folder and double clicking on it, which is awful for security reasons.

Is it possible to make it so that the text file can't be accessed outside the program?

Comment: Hello! Hmmm.... I don't want to be pushy but may I ask if why would you not consider a database perhaps? like probably sqlite? Probably you might have reasons that you need to have it on a `.txt` file. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be txt, I'm a very beginner programmer learning on a by-project basis. I simply do not know anything other than txt for now. Also I don't need a VERY secure database, the loging system is stored locally (on the ccmputer of the person using the program). I need really little security, just the bare minimum since it's a small script. Im going to google sqlite and see what I get. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, as long as you are storing data on your disk, the data will always be readable.

Actuall when you uses .txt, it means that you want it to be readable to others. If you are looking for security, you have to encode your content(Account & Password) to something else that only your program can read.
something similar to chaning 'A' to 'B', '1' to '0', '0' to '7'.....
or another approach used by modern Login Sytem: [Hashing your Password](https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there isn't a way to securely store a password in clear in a file in the file system.

You can arrange things so that a file can only be read by a specific account on the system.  However, someone with admin privilege will (probably) be able to do things that will give themselves access.  And there will most likely be other ways to break file system security in some circumstances.

The ideal solution is to NOT store the password.  Even storing it encrypted with a private key is a bad idea.

Creating and storing a "salted hash" of a password *can be* secure ... provided that there is no way that a "bad guy" can capture the password characters before they have been hashed, but I don't think that is going to help you here ... since you apparently need to be able to recover the actual password.

Maybe the best approach would be to investigate "password safe" or "key chain" products that are provided by the client's OS or web browser.  Unfortunately, this is going to be platform specific.

You could also just "hide" the file containing the password, or (reversibly) obscure the password.  But this is insecure.  It can easily be defeated by reverse engineering the steps that your code is taking to hide the password.

Comment: Yes ... but the point of storing a salted password hash is to make it computationally hard(er) to guess the original password from the hash.  (And per my edits, this is probably not a solution for the OP's problem anyway.)

Comment: The resuliting program is gonna be turned into an exe file, can the source code be read from the exe file? If it can't, I can just hash the password and call it a day.

Comment: The solution should depend on the level of security. If the password should, say, prevent your partner from accessing a list of Christmas presents, a simple encoding of the pw will be sufficient (unless they are very determined and good hackers).

Comment: It's an automated solution that updates listings on a very local ecomerce(you have to do this manually everyday and it's annoying), it doesnt really need that much security since the accounts arent really worth stealing, but I have to garantee a minimum level of security since people tend to use the same password for everything...

Comment: *"I have to guarantee a minimum level of security since people tend to use the same password for everything..."* - Guaranteeing "a minimal level of security" is a vague and ambiguous requirement, but the only way to guarantee that the password cannot be stolen from the user's machine is not to store it.  (But using the platform's keyring is probably secure enough.)

Comment: *"... can the source code be read from the exe file?"* - You can't (literally) read source code from an exe file, but you don't need the source code to reverse engineer an exe file!  If someone can get hold of the exe file, they can work out what it does.